Is it possible to transform MIQP into MILP without introducing new variable?
I have a QP optimization problem in the form
$$\min {\bf x}^T{\bf Qx}-{\bf c}^T{\bf x}$$
here $\bf Q$ is a symmetric matrix.
$\bf x$ is the optimization variable, and it is binary.
Is there a way to make it MILP without introducing any new variable?
It does not need to be an exact equivalent form. Some approximation is also fine.
